# How to convert a string to an integer in Lean 4?

Tags: lean

The documentation of Lean 4 seems incomplete and/or not user-friendly at this point.

I am hoping someone who knows can help me out.

```
def main : IO Unit := do
    let stdin ← IO.getStdin
    let stdout ← IO.getStdout
  
    stdout.putStrLn "Pick a number between 0 and 38"
    let i ← stdin.getLine
```

Comment: Perhaps this code sample helps:
https://github.com/leanprover/lean4-samples/tree/main/GuessMyNumber

Answer (score 1):

As Moritz Firsching points out, Lean4 defines a `String.toNat` which will return a `Option Nat`. Because of that you have also to adapt your code to handle the possibility of failure in the conversion:

```
def main : IO Unit := do
  let stdin ← IO.getStdin
  let stdout ← IO.getStdout
  stdout.putStrLn "Pick a number between 0 and 38"
  let i ← String.trim <$> stdin.getLine

  match i.toNat? with
  | none => IO.println "No Int given"
  | some i => IO.println s!"You picked {i}"
```

Hope that it helps!